# SSH "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: centos, ssh

Question with the same answer did not resolve my issue. I am sorry if this does not follow proper guide lines, new to stack exchange.

I have a (newly installed but not new) server on my work network. At my place of employment there is a 2 teir network set up. the external IP(e.e.e.e) at specified port (eeee) points to the IP of my router (x.x.x.x) at port 22 then my router does port forwarding to the servers ip (y.y.y.y) at port 22.

This is the issue i am having:

- on work netwrok `ssh user@y.y.y.y` WORKS
- on place of employment network `ssh user@e.e.e.e -p eeee` WORKS
- on any other network `ssh user@e.e.e.e -p eeee` DOES NOT WORK. I get "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" after some time of waiting.

I am wondering if there are some config changed like host in ssh_config that need to be adjusted. but this is a guess.

I have look around for a while for some answers and I have changed some settings in my sshd_config `UseDNS no` `GSSAPIAuthentication no`

I am able to tellnet the external IP and port and it connects. but the ssh does not.

None of these seem to work. I have uninstalled and re-installed Openssh on the server thinking it may have been some bad back end. If you need any other info I will get it for you. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am at my witts end with this, been trying to get this to work for over a month.

OS on server: Centos7

Thanks!